Teradata connection issue within django
I am able to connect to teradata from django app in home network. But not able to do so from office network. I am working for a banking company and there are network restrictions. One resolution was to update routetable using powershell commands with admin access. But doing so is not allowing to run the app still. How can this issue be resolved?
Tried updating routetable manually using powershell commands. But that is not helping. Can anyone suggest how to resolve the issue?
